# How to apply a transformation to View?

Tags: android

I have a custom `View` with overridden `onDraw`:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawPath(m_path, m_paint);
}
```

I want to make it possible to pan/scale/rotate the view. And I do not want to redraw it every time user moves his finger. My idea is to apply a transformation matrix to the view in response to user gestures.

I know there is a method `ImageView.setImageMatrix` that seems to do what I need, but I have not an `ImageView`, but a custom `View`.

In iOS, I used `CALayer` and `myLayer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMake...`.

How would you suggest to handle it in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are drawing a `Path`, you can apply a `Matrix` (as Android calls an affine transform) to your path:

On user interaction, you would update the matrix, then your view would call:

```
        m_path.transform(m_matrix, m_path_draw);
```

See [Path#transform | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#transform(android.graphics.Matrix,%20android.graphics.Path))

And in `onDraw()`, you would call:

```
        canvas.drawPath(m_path_draw, m_paint);
```

Alternatively, `Canvas` has a `setMatrix()` method:

```
        canvas.save();
        canvas.setMatrix(m_matrix);
        canvas.drawPath(m_path, m_paint);
        canvas.restore();
```

Whichever method you use, I would recommend having your `Matrix` be a member variable so you only construct it once during your custom view construction.

Comment: Applying the matrix will occur in `onDraw`, right? It means that every time user pans the view it will be redrawn. This is the thing I want to avoid. I would like to move rendered view as a whole.

Comment: Keep in mind, redrawing the view is the only way the screen changes.  Every time you scroll, every time you swipe, `onDraw` is called many many times.  I've written a pinch/zoom image control with a fling, i.e. the view matrix is set in `computeScroll` which is called every time the fling animation is updated.  In the underlying `ImageView`, the matrix is applied in `onDraw` to the canvas with `canvas.concat(mDrawMatrix)`.  The fling animation is smooth and responsive.  If you're concerned about performance, just try this method first.  I predict that you're going to be pleasantly surprised.

Comment: I've looked at some of the graphics code with regards to matrix.  First of all, most of it happens in a JNI native layer, where it's all written in C/C++.  Second, the matrix values themselves are stored using a nonstandard floating-point format called "16.16" which is optimized for rapid arithmetic calculation.  Google has put an enormous amount of effort into optimizing graphical operations.  Using a matrix for view transforms will not be an issue.